# Identify Languages supported in Font file using Directwrite for windows OS

Tags: fonts

I need to identify the languages supported in the fonts such as english, arabic, hindi etc..
I search in DWrite documentation in microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/direct-write-portal but couldn't find anything.

it will be very helpful if some one help me to find the supported languages in a font file in Windows.

In MAC, we can find this using kCTFontLanguagesAttribute using coreText library
 `reinterpret_cast<CFArrayRef>(CTFontDescriptorCopyLocalizedAttribute(descriptor,kCTFontLanguagesAttribute, nullptr))`

I am looking similar thing for Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an exact equivalent in DWrite to what kCTFontLanguagesAttribute returns.

My understanding is that the CoreText API looks first for information in a font's ['meta' table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/meta) regarding supported languages, if present in the font. If not, it looks for hints in the [OS/2 table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2) (it might look at either Unicode range or code page range fields), or compares the font's character coverage (in the ['cmap' table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cmap) with other APIs using ICU that can report lists of characters required by different languages.

DWrite can return the same information from the font's 'meta' table, if present in the font by using the [IDWriteFont::GetInformationalStrings method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefont-getinformationalstrings) with DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_DESIGN_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE_TAG or DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_SUPPORTED_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE_TAG.

If the font doesn't have a 'meta' table (not uncommon), then you could use [IDWriteFont1::GetUnicodeRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_1/nf-dwrite_1-idwritefont1-getunicoderanges) to determine the font's character coverage, and then you should be able to call Windows [ICU APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu-#:%7E:text=International%20Components%20for%20Unicode%20%28ICU%29%20is%20a%20mature%2C,applications%20the%20same%20results%20across%20on%20all%20platforms) to get character requirements for different languages to compare, just as the Mac API is doing.

Comment: thanks it helped.. just a question DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_SUPPORTED_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE_TAG this is supported in windows 10 DWrite. So how would this help to run in windows 7 and windows 8.1?

Comment: Check out Project Reunion and DWriteCore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/project-reunion/

Comment: This Project Reunion is used for different OS of Windows 10. But My requirement is that my application which is developed on Windows 10 DWriteCore APIs, which If I run on Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 OS, then it won't work or will it work?

Comment: Sorry, I thought Project Reunion was also targeting earlier Windows versions. Perhaps it will eventually? If not, you might need to use IDWriteFontFace::TryGetFontTable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefontface-trygetfonttable) and parse data, or find a different library that does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

using [IDWriteFontSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefontset) and [DWRITE_FONT_PROPERTY_ID_SUPPORTED_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE_TAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/ne-dwrite_3-dwrite_font_property_id) also We can get the list of supported languages information.